# How to fix ruby syntax highlighting broken in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

When i use `<<-SQL` construction for insert SQL to my ruby code, syntax highlihting was broken:

[image]

So, my questions is:
1. is the way to fix this problem?
2. How i can find problem solution if google not understand `<<-SQL` character combination?

Comment: the `<<-` syntax is called [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document). Beyond that, not sure, don't have Visual Studio and my editor manages that code just fine. Could try putting the ending `SQL` in the heredoc at the far left column, with no spaces before it and see if that works, some things require the ending delimiter to not have spaces before it. Ruby handles the leading spaces just fine, but maybe Visual Studio is having issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem on VS Code, except that I am using PHP but the syntax highlighting always breaks when I use any heredoc or nowdoc; The workaround I found was NOT to indent the closing tag (shown in the image below).

[image: nowdoc without indentation]

Not sure if it's the same case for your Ruby code.